# How to set the navigation bar title and background color dynamically in React Navigation 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation Bar v5 and setting title in App.js but I want to change it dynamically when the screen is displayed.
I tried  `this.props.navigation.navigate('ExistStock', { title: 'WHATEVER' })`  but it doesn't work as it was working in v4.
What are the correct ways to change the navigation bar title and background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it at screenOptions just like you do in V4.

You will have to pass the parameters

```
navigation.navigate('Details', { id: item.id, name: item.name,color:item.color })
```

And in the navigator you can use it as the title and color

```
  <Stack.Screen
        name="Details"
        component={Details}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          title: route.params.name,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: oute.params.color,
          },
        })}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use useFocusEffect from React native navigation with navigation.setOptions to dynamically set the navigation options on render.

```
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';  


const myFunctionalComponent = props => {   

        useFocusEffect(
            useCallback(() => {
                props.navigation.setOptions({
                    title: 'Whatever',
                });
            }, [props.navigation])
        );

...
```

You can apply any of the options listed in the documentation
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#setting-the-header-title

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
        title: "Whatever"
    });
}
```

This can be used add title at the screen or change the title accordingly.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
        title:
    this.state.count === 0
      ? 'Select items'
      : `${this.state.count} items selected`,
});
    });
}
```

Changing the title according to the state of the component.